# Rails 3 Full_Calendar

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

Does anyone know if there is a step-by-step tutorial for intergrating Rails on [Rails 3 fullcalendar](https://github.com/bokmann/rails3_fullcalendar) into an existing Rails app? I have looked at the documentation, implemented what I can, but as a newbie unsure where I may be going wrong... I'm basically looking to see if anyone else has done it and shared their experiences?

Comment: hey have tried reading their read me file and demo pages here: https://github.com/bokmann/rails3_fullcalendar/blob/master/README && http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ cheers

Answer (score 1):

You just need to have the JavaScript files in your [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). You should put it to `/vendor/assets/javascripts/fullcalendar` and then include it in your `application.js` via

```
//= require_tree ./fullcalendar
[...other scripts]
$(document).ready(function() {

  // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // put your options and callbacks here
  })

});
```

In your view you have to include the following element to place the calendar there:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Just try it. It is not that hard. Ask again if you have more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks Sandro, will give this a try later. I have been placing my Javascripts and stylesheets in app/assets/javascripts and app/assets/stylesheets... I take it this is not correct?

Comment: May have answered my own question by some further reading......vendor/assets is for assets that are owned by outside entities, such as code for JavaScript plugins and CSS frameworks. Is this why i need to place these paticular javascripts in the vendor/assets/javascripts... do i place the stylesheets in the same place?

Comment: IMHO the 'vendor/assets' and the 'app/assets' path are almost similiar. But it is the recommended way to have scripts and files that are 3rd party ones in the 'vendor/assets' path. It is also recommended to have the stylesheets in 'vendor/assets/stylesheets' (while keeping the path-structure) but I prefer having the files from one plugin alltogether in 'vendor/assets/javascripts/myExtension'.

Comment: One other thing ( Sorry for the bombardment of questions) if i want to add jquery.js to the assets pipeline ( in /vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery ) does //= require_tree ./fullcalendar become //= require_tree ./fullcalendar/jquery

Comment: Thanks again Sandro, so just to confirm full calendar has three seperate javascript files, do i put them in one folder ( fullcalendar) with each file within the folder or put each file seperate. so 'vendor/assets/jquery   'vendor/assets/fullcalendar   'vendor/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js

Comment: Maybe you should watch this Railscast for understanding the asset pipeline: http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline.
You do not need to add the jQuery again. It is already in Rails if you have //= require jquery. You can keep the folder-structure of the plugin as is and just do //= require_tree ./[top_folder_of_the_plugin]